# What is a good "NOP" executable to start on Windows that is built-in and does nothing?

Tags: windows, testing, process

I'm writing a library that deals with child processes. In order to write tests for it I require the ability to start a child process that exits immediately.

What's a good built-in executable on Windows that I can use as a "dummy process" for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- rundll32.exe (GUI application with no UI)
- subst.exe (no console output)
- xcopy.exe
- find.exe
- `control.exe /!` (GUI application with no UI)
- `cmd.exe /c exit`
- cscript.exe

Comment: Very nice list, thanks! Better than what I had come up with.